# Redux Saga: Waiting for saga fully completed

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

How to waiting for saga fully completed and after execute some other code.
I have saga such like this:

```
//users sagas file
export function* saveUsersRequest() {
  yield takeLatest(SAVE_USER_REQUEST, function* (payload) {
    const { user } = payload
    const url = '/api/users'

    const request = postForResponse(url, user)  //axios request
    const { response, error } = yield call(request)
    if (response) {
      yield put({
        type: SAVE_USER_SUCCESS,
        data: response.data
      })
    } else {
      yield put({
        type: SAVE_USER_ERROR,
        error: error.message || 'Failed to save user'
      })
    }
  })
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(someOtherSaga),
    fork(saveUsersRequest)
  ])
}


// import to root saga

import users from './users'

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    // .... other sagas
    users()
  ])
}
```

In my component I dispatch action and need waiting for saveUsersRequest will finished (all inner calls and actions must be finished too). I tried to wrap it in Promise like:

```
// this component connected to Redux store
class MyComp extends Component {
    handleSaveClick = () => {
        Promise.resolve(this.props.saveUser(params)).then(() => {
        const { saveUserError } = this.props
        if (!saveUserError) {
          toggle()
        }
      })
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleSaveClick} />
    }
}
```

Its not work because inner API call finished after toggle() call. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What does toggle() do? And in which method if this promise?

Comment: @GabrielFerrarini toggle method close modal window, it is in button click listener. I will update code now

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how reudx + redux-saga work together. 1. Your saveUser method is dispatching an action the the store and returning immediately. There's no async code for your promise to wait. 2. Your saga code will not run until your handleSaveClick has returned. 3. Since your promise returned immediately your saga will also only run after your promise callback. Without knowing how you show your modal is hard to help with a solution.

Comment: Also, the `take` effect creator has no second parameter. If you want it to run only once use it like this: `const payload = yield take(SAVE_USER_REQUEST);` If you want it to run multiple times, use it like this: `yield takeEvery(SAVE_USER_REQUEST, function* (payload) {`

Comment: @MartinKadlec Yes, you are right, I was sealed when I wrote an example.